# Не удается зарегистрировать пользователя с помощью почты и пароля на Firebase

Tags: ios, objective-c, oauth2, firebase

Не удается зарегистрировать пользователя с помощью почты и пароля на Firebase. Сделал все как сказано в официальной документации но xcode выдает ошибку такого рода "The email address is already in use by another account". Пробовал с других почтовых ящиков, но проблема такая же. В базе зарегистрировал пользователя но с его почтой и паролем даже в блок не могу войти, и ошибки никакой не получаю. Вот мой код...

Может кто сталкивался с подобным, подскажите в чем проблема, буду очень признателен!

```
//вход

[[FIRAuth auth] signInWithEmail:self.userNameTextField.text
                       password:self.passwordTextField.text
                     completion:^(FIRUser * _Nullable user, NSError * _Nullable error) {
                         if (!error) {

                         } else {
                             NSLog(@"Error %@", error.localizedDescription);
                         }
                     }];


//регистрация

NSString *email = self.emailRegistrationTextField.text;
NSString *password = self.passwordRegistrationTextField.text;

[[FIRAuth auth] createUserWithEmail:email
                           password:password
                         completion:^(FIRUser * _Nullable user, NSError * _Nullable error) {
                             if (!error) {

                                 self.fireUser = [[TSFireUser alloc] initWithDictionary:(NSDictionary *)user];

                             } else {
                                 NSLog(@"Error - %@", error.localizedDescription);
                             }
                         }];
```

В файле AppDeldegate.m инициализировал протокол [FIRApp configure]; все модули подключил...

Answer (score 1):

Проблема в том что Вы должны проверять залогинен ли пользователь или еще нет. Используйте свойство currentUser у FIRAuth. (Если оно не nil тогда пользователь уже вошел, иначе, еще нет). Что бы выйти надо использовать метод logOut у FIRAuth.